# navigator.userAgent not giving full user agent String

Tags: javascript, user-agent, mobile-devices

Currently getting this value:
**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0**

but i have tested online my Current user agent is:
**Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-de; Galaxy S II Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30**

i have tried with

```
<script>
document.write(window.navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
document.write(navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

It is giving me 
**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0** 
not full String as i want.

It is not giving any information about mobile device or browser.

Do i need to add anything else to get full User Agent String **??**

Answer (score 0):

Refer to following documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

It is providing you a user agent string with all information. It is assuming you are using a WOW64 Windows device for some reason.